# Can't install libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb on Renesas R-Car H3 (H3ULCB)

Tags: opencv, gtk, opkg

I am trying to run object detection algorithm (which is using OpenCV 2.4.13.7) on H3ULCB. It is giving libGTK as shown below

```
root@h3ulcb:/media/2.4.13_algo_target_# ./main_

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or [ 1976.641753] audit: type=1706
Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvWaitKey, fil7
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /media/2.4.13.7_pckage/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:567: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Wiy
Aborted (core dumped)}
```

To solve the error , I tried to install libGTK package (libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb) on H3ULCB, but its not getting installed to the target.

```
* pkg_extract_data_file_names_to_stream: Failed to extract data.tar.gz from package '/media/libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb'.
* pkg_get_installed_files: Error extracting file list from /media/libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb.
* opkg_install: Cannot install package libgtk2.0-dev.
```

BSP and SDK for H3ULCB are build using yocto, details are listed below:

Yocto version: 2.23
Poky: 2.1.3

1. The same error is resolved on the native Linux (Ubuntu16.04) by installing the `libgtk2.0` library from apt-get manager. But package manager `apt` and `dpkg` is not getting installed on the target. I tried to add these managers in the yocto layers while building the image.
2. Currently Available package manager on H3ULCB is OPKG. Since OPKG works on .IPK packages but not .IPK packages on available for `libgtk2.0`, I have converted the .deb package to a .IPK package .While executing the .IPK package on H3ulcb:

   ```
   root@h3ulcb:/media# opkg install libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.ipk 
   Collected errors:
    * open_outer: Failed to open package 'libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.ipk': Unrecognized archive format
    * pkg_extract_control_file_to_stream: Failed to extract control.tar.gz from package 'libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.ipk'.
    * pkg_init_from_file: Failed to extract control file from libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.ipk.
   ```
3. In the package `libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb`, there are 3 files

   - `control.tar.gz`
   - `data.tar.xz`
   - `debian-binary`

   while executing the .deb file on H3ULCB, the error showed `data.tar.gz` instead of `data.tar.xz` as given below:

   ```
   pkg_extract_data_file_names_to_stream: Failed to extract data.tar.gz from package '/media/libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.31-2_arm64.deb'.
   ```

I have converted data.tar.xz to data.tar.gz, but how to pack these files 3 files back to .deb package?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to rebuild OpenCV with GTK support disabled. You don't really need it on an embedded target. You care about the detection algorithm, but the visualization could be done on a remote computer, using the data sent by your program through some network.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply. Visualization will be done on Renesas board by connecting monitor using micro HDMI. So GTK will be needed.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having similar issue with NXP iMX8M. I've tried to add 'libgtk2.0-dev' in opencv recipe DEPENDS but Yocto crashes saying 'nothing provides' that package